# Obtain missing records from 2 queries not tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know how to find a common value between tables that's missing but two queries?

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GENG.GlGroup
FROM MCMGenHistory GENH 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPZCGenGroup GENG 
        ON GENG.ExpenseCode = substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3)
WHERE SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'
```

Results:

```
10
7
8
5
1
6
9
4
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GENG.GlGroup 
from RPZCGenGroup GENG
```

Results:

```
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I want the records that are missing, e.g. 2 and 3. The problem is that the first query makes use of the same table but with a filter.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. if the first query returns the results that you want then what's the problem? - maybe give more details about expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that you want all the records from the results from *Query 2* that aren't in the results from *Query 1*, a quick and easy way is to use `EXCEPT`:

```
[Query 2]
EXCEPT
[QUERY 1]
```

Specifically:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GENG.GlGroup 
FROM RPZCGenGroup GENG
EXCEPT
SELECT GENG.GlGroup
FROM MCMGenHistory GENH 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPZCGenGroup GENG 
        ON GENG.ExpenseCode = substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3)
WHERE SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'
```

You probably don't want to use the `DISTINCT` in the second query either as it'll probably decrease performance and have no effect on the results.

Further documentation: [EXCEPT and INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) @ MSDN

It looks like what you're really after is all the records in *RPZCGenGroup* that don't have any matching records in *MCMGenHistory* with a GlCode that starts with 'P'. The quick and easy version of this is to use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT GENG.GlGroup 
FROM RPZCGenGroup GENG
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 
    FROM MCMGenHistory GENH
    WHERE substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3) = GENG.ExpenseCode
        AND SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'
)
```

Performance of `NOT EXISTS` is likely to be an issue so you can/should replace it with a proper outer join (note @Love2Learn's assessment too):

```
SELECT GENG.GlGroup 
FROM RPZCGenGroup GENG
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MCMGenHistory GENH
        ON substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3) = GENG.ExpenseCode
            AND SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'
WHERE GENH.GlCode IS NULL
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was after!! thanks a million            SELECT DISTINCT GENG.GlGroup 
FROM RPZCGenGroup GENG
EXCEPT
SELECT GENG.GlGroup
FROM MCMGenHistory GENH 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN RPZCGenGroup GENG 
        ON GENG.ExpenseCode = substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3)
WHERE SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'

Answer (score 5):

When you add your criteria outside of the `JOIN` criteria you effectively turn your `OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. If I understand you correctly you want the GENG.GlGroup values where you join criteria does not apply so why not just keep all your culling criteria within the `OUTER JOIN` logic and get the records from RPZCGenGroup where GENH.GlGroup Is Null?

```
SELECT  DISTINCT GENG.GlGroup
FROM    MCMGenHistory GENH 
RIGHT   OUTER JOIN RPZCGenGroup GENG 
        ON  GENG.ExpenseCode=substring(GENH.GlCode,13,3)
        AND SUBSTRING(GENH.GlCode,1,1)='P'
WHERE   GENH.GlCode Is Null
```

Comment: This does not work, as firstly GENH dont have a column GLGROUP

Comment: Then use `GENH.GlCode`. It doesn't matter which field you use. Looks like you got this from @Alkini's post though so you're good, cool.